# Nsight debugger doesn't go to device functions

Tags: cuda, nsight, optimus

I have a notebook with a optimus tech. graphic card. So, I have installed Bumblebee on my ubuntu 12.10 (64-bit). I have installed CUDA 5 and it runs with "optirun". But I have a problems with debugging in Nsight (eclipse); I can debug the host code, but it skips device's functions!

I have seen some related posts, but my issue has not been resolved yet. I tried to run Nsight with "optirun"; and also added optirun before gdb.

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: You may be interested in this [Question/Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13609233/how-to-start-debug-version-of-project-in-nsight-with-optirun-command/13611344#13611344)

Comment: it's quite different from what I'm asking. He had some problem with building. My project it's been built. When I try it in the debug mode, I can only trace host code and the device code will be skipped.

Comment: The answer provided by @Eugene indicated that debug with optirun is not something that's been tested or validated with Nsight EE, but that you might try creating a run script the way he suggested in his answer to see if you can debug device code using that method.

Comment: Do you compile via nvcc with the -G option? It compiles device debug information

Comment: From the looks of it, your device code is simply not ran. Make sure you check return codes of all CUDA calls and have cudaDeviceSynchronize after the kernel call (with its return value checked). Said that, it is likely that your device code is not executed in your app because of optirun configuration - see my reply to the question referenced by @RobertCrovella

Comment: I get the correct output when I run it (the problem is only with debug). However I added Synchronize and nothing changed.